# Ejecutable script to replace an entire line of code from custom directory

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command-line, text-processing

Is there any way to replace a line of js code via script?. Maybe with sed... I would like to replace an url attribute of an Ajax function with another url. The line of code that i'd like to change via script is in the route:
**website-project/src/client-side/js/custom-scripts.js**  the entire line i would like to change is:

```
url: "https://us-central1-develop-website.cloudfunctions.net/send_contact",

to

url: "https://us-central1-production-website-prd.cloudfunctions.net/send_contact"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed, you can do it like this:

```
sed -i 's/url: "https:\/\/us-central1-develop-website.cloudfunctions.net\/send_contact"/url: "https:\/\/us-central1-production-website-prd.cloudfunctions.net\/send_contact"/' website-project/src/client-side/js/custom-scripts.js
```

To make it a bit more readable in script, you can decompose it with the help of variables:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

from='url: "https://us-central1-develop-website.cloudfunctions.net/send_contact"'
to='url: "https://us-central1-production-website-prd.cloudfunctions.net/send_contact"'

target_file=website-project/src/client-side/js/custom-scripts.js

sed -i "$(printf 's+%s+%s+' "$from" "$to")" "$target_file"
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the help, it doesn't work, it trows:sed: can't read website-project/src/client-side/js/custom-scripts.js No such file or directory

Comment: You must replace `website-project/src/client-side/js/custom-scripts.js` by the full path to your file, something like `/var/www/website-project/.../custom-scripts.js`, or `~/website-project/.../custom-scripts.js` or anything else depending on where you js file is located

Comment: I figured out! I was wrong in the path. It worked! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am mistaken, this Ed script should do the trick:-

```
#!/bin/sh

cat >> edrep.txt << EOF

/develop-website/    # This command will get you to the line with this string.
s/develop-website/production-website-prd/    # This will modify the line for you.
wq    # This writes to the file and quits.

EOF

ed -s website-project/src/client-side/js/custom-scripts.js < edrep.txt
rm -v ./edrep.txt
```